# Number of attempts is inaccurate (for loop)

Tags: java, for-loop

Is it possible to display the number of guesses/attempts made not counting the ones when an exception is thrown? Because the number of attempts I'm getting when I execute the program includes the exceptions. I used decrement for whenever an exception is thrown but that's not working.

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 50;
        int rndm = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + 1) + min;
        System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50!");
        for (int x = 1; x > 0; x++) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Guess the randomized number: ");
            int jv = sc.nextInt();
            try {
                if (jv < min || jv > max) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
                else if (jv >= min && jv <= max) {
                    if (jv == rndm) {
                        System.out.println("The randomized number is " + rndm + ". "
                                + "Your guess is correct!");
                        int atmpts = x;
                        System.out.println("You got it in " + atmpts + " attempts!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else if (jv > rndm) {
                        System.out.println("Too high! Try again.");
                    }
                    else if (jv < rndm) {
                        System.out.println("Too low! Try again.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input! Input must be a number from 1 to 50. Try again.");
                x = x--;
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input! Input must be a number. Try again.");
                x = x--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why use this `for (int x = 1; x > 0; x++)` loop.  I suggest just having an endless loop, then control your counter variable separately.  e.g. `while (true) {`

Comment: Also it is the general opinion that using exceptions for code control is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create a new `Scanner` each time you need to get input from the user. Create the `Scanner` once, before entering the loop.

This line of code is incorrect:

```java
x = x--;
```

It should be:

```java
--x;
```

Refer to Oracle's Java [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

Here is your code with my corrections as described above:
(Note that I use class [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html) to get a random number.)

```java
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 50;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndm = rand.nextInt(1, 51); // (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + 1) + min;
        System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50!");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int x = 1; x > 0; x++) {
            System.out.print("Guess the randomized number: ");
            int jv = sc.nextInt();
            try {
                if (jv < min || jv > max) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
                else if (jv >= min && jv <= max) {
                    if (jv == rndm) {
                        System.out.println("The randomized number is " + rndm + ". "
                                + "Your guess is correct!");
                        int atmpts = x;
                        System.out.println("You got it in " + atmpts + " attempts!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else if (jv > rndm) {
                        System.out.println("Too high! Try again.");
                    }
                    else if (jv < rndm) {
                        System.out.println("Too low! Try again.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input! Input must be a number from 1 to 50. Try again.");
                --x;
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input! Input must be a number. Try again.");
                --x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int min = 1;
    int max = 50;
    int rndm = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + 1) + min;
    int x = 0;
    System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50!");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {    
        System.out.print("Guess the randomized number: ");
        int jv = sc.nextInt();
        try {
            if (jv < min || jv > max) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            else if (jv >= min && jv <= max) {
                x++;
                if (jv == rndm) {
                    System.out.println("The randomized number is " + rndm + ". "
                            + "Your guess is correct!");
                    int atmpts = x;
                    System.out.println("You got it in " + atmpts + " attempts!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else if (jv > rndm) {
                    System.out.println("Too high! Try again.");
                }
                else if (jv < rndm) {
                    System.out.println("Too low! Try again.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Input must be a number from 1 to 50. Try again.");
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Input must be a number. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to create a new `Scanner` instance in each loop iteration, is there?